# codeigniter - Could not maintain shopping cart session as CI database session management code regenerates session id

Tags: codeigniter, php

1. I am displaying a products section where there is an add to cart button.
2. The user may or may not be logged in.
3. Instead of maintaining the cart items in session i maintain it in the database with the current session id as reference.
4. After a few navigation or default session time out the session id is regenerated.
5. So the current session id does not match with the items added by the user in the database.
6. So the total items and amount which i display at the top of the page because zero.
7. I had maintained the cart items in the session in the  previous projects so i haven't had any problems.
8. I am using code igniter frame work

What should i do to sync the regenerated session id of codeigniter and the session id of the cart items. I am using Native Session in codeigniter rather than the default session management which comes with codeigniter. The reason is the session does not work in IE6 because i hope IE6 is not understanding CI's headers or some thing like that.

I want to maintain the cart items in database only. What shall i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use standard PHP sessions - track your own session ID and store that in the DB.  Skip the regenerated CI-SessionID entirely.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Of course, the downside to this is the sessions aren't stored as cookies in this manner so when a user's session expires - they lose their basket.  But you can work around this yourself with either a manual cookie store, or force the user to register/login to save basket data.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the [Native Session of CI](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session/)